# What does "Ma tant'è" mean?

Tags: idioms, word-meaning, meaning

I know that "tant'è che" means "so much that" or "moreover", but this translation doesn't fit in this passage:

"[...]E lei invece si chiama Maria, è mia cugina. Ci andavo d'accordo da piccola, ora la trovo molto antipatica. Ma tant'è...

Comunque...[...]"

What does "ma tant'è" mean here?

Comment: I am not sure that  "tant'è che" means "so much that".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Tant'è" literally means "so much it is". If that is all that you can say about a situation it probably means that there is really little worth adding. You just accept the situation as it is, whether it be nice or ugly.

Answer (score 12):

I think you received pretty good explanations of what "ma tant'è" is suppose to mean but the translations are quite literal and don't sound right to me.

The best translation I can come up with is: "but yeah.. It is what it is", which is something I've heard from native English speakers.

Answer (score 6):

Used like this, *tant'è* is just an idiom meaning “what's the good?” or “...and there's an end to it”, i.e., when one acknowledges a situation one more or less disapproves of and that apparently cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

When used at the end of the phrase the exact translation should be "but so be it."

e.g:

> "Oggi è brutto tempo, ma tant'è".
> "Today the weather is bad, but so be it".

Answer (score -1):

It appears to mean 'in any event'/'in any case'.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/tanto

there they have 'tanto è'

Comment: Thanks! could you please elaborate on how is it different?